# priority using a date or integer column in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I want a priority column in a todolist that I can have in a join table with a many to many relationship in a rails application.

e.g. 
products
shops
products_shops

in the products_shops table I have a priority, when it is the same shop - they can move the priority of a product up or down. I was thinking to have an integer or date field that would help achieve this.

I've tried several ways

e.g. give all records the same date, last record id, add one second to date, sort by oldest first) not really sure how to go about it.

Hoping for suggestions, I'm not looking for a queue structure as they have to move between rows on screen.

Comment: have you tried `acts_as_list` https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list?

Comment: No, I implemented something similar myself by incrementing a column to raise it's order but this does more - I will give it a try